# What is the difference between the S.E. of an estimator and the estimator for the S.E.?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I am a bit confused between the standard error of an estimator and the estimator for the standard error. A standard error is the standard deviation of a point estimator. Given i.i.d bernoulli random variables $B_1,B_2,\cdots B_n$, an unbiased estimator for the true proportion of successes is 
$$
P=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n B_i}{n}.
$$
We know that the standard deviation for $P$, or the standard error, is $\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$ where $p$ is the true success rate of the bernoulli random variables $B$. So  $\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$ is the S.E. of the estimator.

In a hypothesis test, when we derive the null distribution of the estimator, we can mathematically calculate the exact standard error of the estimator because we can assume a $p$, which is often $0.5$, using the formula above. But what if we are not doing a hypothesis testing? Suppose we are now trying to get an estimate for the variance of the estimator for the true proportion. We surveyed 10 samples, each containing $n$ observations of $B$. If we want to estimate the variance of the point estimator, we will have to use the formula 
$$
S^2=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}(p_i-\bar{p})^2}{10}
$$
where $p_i$ is the proportion of successes for each sample and $\bar{p}$ is the average proportion of successes across all 10 samples. This formula is an estimator for the variance of the estimator for the true proportion, $p$. So I cannot use an arbitrary $p$, say $p_5$, to estimate the variance of the estimator using the formula
$$
\left(\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}\right)^2=\frac{p(1-p)}{n},
$$
right?

Comment: I ran some simulations using R and it seems like $\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$ is an upward biased estimator for the S.E.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not doing a hypothesis test, an estimator of the standard error you derived for the proportion $p$ is simply $$\sqrt{\frac{\bar x(1 - \bar x)}{n}},$$ which is a statistic that depends only on the observations.  Here I used $\bar x$ to denote the sample mean or sample proportion of $1$ outcomes.  We can also call it $\hat p = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n B_i$.

Comment: Why is this an estimator? Isn't it just the exact standard error for $p$? An unbiased estimator for the standard error is $S^2=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}(p_i-\bar{p})^2}{10}$ , right?

Comment: An estimator is a statistic that does not depend on any unknown parameters.  I didn't say whether the estimator I provided was biased or not; you only asked about the difference in meaning of "standard error of an estimator" and "estimator of standard error."  The standard error of an estimator clearly is **not** itself an estimator, since it is a function of the unknown parameter $p$ (in your case).  But if I wanted an estimator of the standard error  (of the parameter $p$, one such estimator is the one I wrote in my answer.

Comment: So your answer to my final question is I can use $p_5$ to estimate the variance of the estimator, right?